# Tomcat does not shut down correctly with init.d script on system-shutdown - restart prevented

Tags: bash, redhat, tomcat, rhel7, init.d

I want to start Apache Tomcat 7 on my Redhat 7 server (RHEL7) automatically at system startup.

In order to do that, I did the following steps:

- creation of the following init.d script and make it executable (is working fine)
- place link of the init.d tomcat script in the rc-files (actually is working fine too)

The problem is that Tomcat cannot start because the corresponding ports, especially the AJP-Port, is already in use (only after restart of system; a simple usage of the init.d script does not cause the problem). My guess is that it either does not shutdown properly or it is started twice and causes the problem that way.

If I reboot the system, Tomcat tries to start. When I try to access my Webpage, I only get a blank page.

This is from `catalina.out` where it begins to fail (example of failure with port 8005, but I have the same issue with 8009 and 8080):

```
20-Apr-2020 20:24:00.813 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT has finished in 79 ms
20-Apr-2020 20:24:00.821 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
20-Apr-2020 20:24:00.831 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 58427 ms
20-Apr-2020 20:24:00.831 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

20-Apr-2020 20:24:00.832 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
20-Apr-2020 20:24:00.832 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Apr-2020 20:24:00.832 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
2020-04-20 20:24:00,856 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.x.shutdown                   - Stopping XWiki...
```

After I do a `pgrep java`, I have to kill the process manually. Then I can start Tomcat without problems.

Of course I can manually kill the process using `pkill -9 java` and start it afterwards. Since this process is to be automated, I cannot simply kill the process every time.

I tested the automatic-startup on my Debian 9 server with Tomcat 8 – there everything works fine.

Do you have an idea how I can solve or at least work around the error?

**Appendix**

My server.xml file:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->

    <!-- <Connector port="8009"
    enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3"         URIEncoding="UTF-8" /> -->

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               proxyName="example.com"
               address="localhost" 
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" 
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    address="127.0.0.1"/>   



    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
        internalProxies="127\.0\.[0-1]\.1"
        remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
        requestAttributesEnabled="true"
        protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"
        protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https"/>

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      [...]
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

`catalina.out` **on shutdown (extract):**

```
20-Apr-2020 20:22:26.607 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.xpn.xwiki.store.migration.AbstractDataMigrationManager.ThreadLock] (value [com.xpn.xwiki.store.migration.AbstractDataMigrationManager$ThreadLock@7f9e8cb9]) and a value of type [java.lang.Integer] (value [0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
20-Apr-2020 20:22:26.607 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.logging.MDCLoggingContext$1] (value [org.apache.solr.logging.MDCLoggingContext$1@21089b81]) and a value of type [java.lang.Integer] (value [0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
20-Apr-2020 20:22:26.623 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
20-Apr-2020 20:22:26.714 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Apr-2020 20:22:26.767 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
20-Apr-2020 20:22:26.768 INFO [Thread-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Comment: Have you followed some tutorial? If yes, could you please post the link to it. You are using init, but systemd is prefered in RHEL 7. Check this DO [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7).

Comment: Rhel7 uses systemd. I suggest you write a proper unit file rather than trying to debug a legacy init script. I would try something like this: https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/e6e99dad070a78d5dab24ff3ae032ed1